Help me finding a movie from a trailer I saw on facebook
An young girl starts to see a woman from distance but not coming close enough. Waving, talking, watching, and standing. She starts to talk to her black friend and asks him to go to the woman and talk to her. He agrees, does it. Walking to the woman and she has told him something that he looked back to the young girl and ran for life.
The young girl was shocked then started to continue running and the woman kept following everywhere. Tired from running and moved to LA (I believe), she meets black woman and makes friends with her. Later tells her secret and asks to do the same, but with a call on phone. Black woman agrees, they take calls each other at car and then black woman leaves the car walks up to the old woman to talk. While the young girl waits inside car watching the black woman walking towards the old woman and talking, I am not sure if she heard something. But the black woman started to run too and left with taxi.
Can you help finding movie, please?

I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to contain any SF&F elements.

@Garik - If there are any science fiction or fantasy elements in this movie, please edit the question to highlight them more clearly.

I am voting to reopen this question because it is very likely about an episode of Doctor Who.

This sounds like a clip from a recent Doctor Who episode titled "73 Yards".
This is a synopsis from Wikipedia -

The Doctor and Ruby arrive at a cliffside in Wales. The Doctor accidentally steps on a "fairy circle" and Ruby reads aloud a message written on a scroll placed within it, saying, "Rest in Peace, Mad Jack". Shortly thereafter, the Doctor vanishes. Ruby sees that a mysterious woman has appeared 73 yards away from her, who remains at exactly that distance no matter where Ruby goes. Every person who talks to the woman flees in terror and becomes hostile to Ruby.


This would be a quite a strange memory of the trailer or episode if so. The "young girl" would have to be Ruby, who is not really a young girl (a young woman, maybe). "Her black friend" would have to be the Doctor, who disappears without talking to the mysterious woman, just there one minute and gone the next. It's everyone else who runs away. The  "black woman" would have to be Ruby's mother, and she definitely does not meet her and make friends with her in the episode, since they have already known each other for years. Also, London is not Los Angeles.

@Adamant - it wouldn't be the longest shot I've made on here

Honestly, it sounds like that episode of Doctor Who to me as well. Her mother did talk to the old woman and then wanted nothing to do with her afterwards. Everybody who talked to the old woman ran away. Maybe the details of the trailer she saw were confusing.

Thank you @Radhil, it was Doctor Who 73 Yards. Recognized by actress’s face. Will watch it.
